# Switch between tabs in a fragment tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

1. I have a FragmentTabHost, hosted in a Fragment. The tabHost has 4
   tabs.
2. In first tab fragment, there are two nested fragments.
3. After clicking in a view in first nested fragment, a DialogFragment
   appears, which has a couple of buttons.

After clicking on a button in DialogFragment, I want to switch to tab number 3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Tab Fragment:

```
public void setCurrentTab(int tab_index){
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(tab_index);
    }
```

In click event of the button of DialogFragment:

```
FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)  getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
```